# PySpark not able to move file from local to HDFS

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs

I am running hadoop in my local machine on port 8020. My name nodes exist under path `/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/hdfs/tmp/dfs/name`. I have setup a pySpark project using Conda env and installed pyspark and hdfs3 dependencies.

The following is my code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from hdfs3 import HDFileSystem

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('First Project').getOrCreate()

hdfs = HDFileSystem(host="localhost", port=8020)
hdfs.put("test.csv", "/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/hdfs/tmp/dfs/name/test.csv")
```

I am trying to copy the file from my local file system to HDFS but I am getting the following error:

```
OSError: Could not open file: /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/hdfs/tmp/dfs/name/test.csv, mode: wb Parent directory doesn't exist: /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/hdfs/tmp/dfs/name
```

But I can cd into the same directory and its exists. I am not sure why I get this error.

Also, when I try to do hdfs.mv with same params, I get the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: test.csv
```

Comment: `hdfs3` has nothing to do with spark. You also shouldn't put your DFS data directory inside the homebrew path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to upload a local CSV using Spark you'd need to actually use Spark

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.csv('file:///path/to/file.csv')
df.write.csv(output_path)
```

Otherwise, you cannot "put" into your Homebrew location since that *doesn't exist on HDFS* (at least, not unless you ran `hadoop fs mkdir -p /usr/local/Cellar/...` for some reason)

> when I try to do hdfs.mv with same params ... FileNotFoundError

Because you need to `cd` to the directory with the local CSV first. Otherwise, specify the full path

Comment: Hello, for me i need to upload images and videos files to hdfs, how can i do it ?

Comment: @ABDELLATIFLAGHJAJ In my experience, HDFS isn't meant for such files since they are not splittable file types